# MSBuild successful but Visual Studio failed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

We're using Jenkins to build out projects using msbuild.

I added a project reference to an existing project but forgot to add these new project to all solution files.

I committed but Jenkins told me that everything works fine.
I tried that on command line:

```
msbuild test.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Debug
```

Having a totally cleared working directory that works fine, in Jenkins and on my developing machine. The output told me that msbuild found that project and build it.

But if I open Visual Studio 2017 and try to build that solution, it tells me that the depending project could not be found.

That's correct.

How do I force msbuild to only build projects that are specified in the solution file so that we're able to find all solutions that missed that new project?

BTW: We don't need a hint how to find all solutions that need to contain that new project. Finding that solutions is pretty easy.

Comment: What do you mean "but forgot to add theese new project to all solution files."? Do you me mean you are not commit this new project? Could you please give me some more detail steps to reproduce this issue?

Comment: @Leo-MSFT We're having multiple solutions that all contains a common project. That project got a reference to a new assembly. I only added this project to one solution, the one where I created it, and forgot all other solution files. For better understanding: we're using project references.

Comment: thanks for you reply. Is your project structure like this:https://1drv.ms/i/s!Ai1sp_yvodHfc7qaSvEkVpyMOHc, now, you want to build the specified common project, then able find **all** solutions that missed that new project? AFAIK, we could use command line: "msbuild CommonProjectName.csproj /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Debug" to build the specified in one solution file, we could not to find all solutions that missed that new project except build all solutions.

Comment: @Leo-MSFT Yes our solution structure look like your sample. Mostly. The project itself contains the reference, but the solution file doesn't. It doesn't work to build all solutions because that's what we're currently doing. MSBuild is able to find that missing project even though it is not specified in the solution file. We're looking for a solution that forces MSBuild to only build project specified in solution file.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I force msbuild to only build projects that are specified in the solution file so that we're able to find all solutions that missed that new project?

The correct way to avoid MSBuild's default behavior of rebuilding all the dependencies listed in the solution file is to set the `BuildProjectReferences` property to false, So the build command line should be:

```
MSBuild Test.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Debug /p:BuildProjectReferences=false
```

After using this command line, MSBuild will get the same error with VS, so we're able to find all solutions that missed that new project

[image]

Note: `BuildProjectReferences` will check all the dependencies listed in the solution file, so please keep his value is true, unless used to check the missing dependencies.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This looks exactly like the solution what I was looking for. The error occurs like expected. But if I have a correct solution it doesn't work. A correct solution won't build.

Comment: @Verarind, yes, BuildProjectReferences will check all the dependencies listed in the solution file, so please keep his value is true, unless used to check the missing dependencies.